# How to tell if F-Stat is significant? And at which significance level?

Tags: econometrics

This question has been posted on

http://forums.eviews.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=12403

But no reply.

Question:
How do I tell if the F-stat is significant at 1%, 5%, or 10% level?
Or not significant?[image]

Comment: Reading this will give you the answer.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance#Role_in_statistical_hypothesis_testing

Answer (score 2):

You get:

```
F-statistic          24.60231
Prob(F-statistic)    0.000000
```

You observe that the [p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) is 0.00, so this means that the F-statistic is significant at at 99+%, and also obviously at 95% and 90%.